# Функция удаляющая пробелы в строке

Tags: c, строки

Здравствуйте, написал функцию которая удаляет пробелы в строке, но в некоторых ситуациях она не выводит последний символ.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 81
#define LIM 20

void delSpace(char * str);

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    char string[LIM][SIZE];

    puts("Input text:");

    while (i < LIM && gets(string[i]) != NULL && string[i][0] != '\0')
    {
        delSpace(string[i]);
        puts(string[i]);
        i++;
    }
    puts("Goodbye!");

    return 0;   
}
void delSpace(char * str)
{
    int i, j;
    int len = strlen(str);
    char temp[len];

    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ')
        {
            if (str[i + 1] == ' ')
            {
                i++;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                temp[j] = str[++i];
                j++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            temp[j] = str[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
        str[i] = temp[i];
    str[i] = '\0';
}
```

Вот результат вывода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообщем всегда когда строка заканчивается одним символом, вывод нормальный, а когда последнее слово более одного символа, то последний не выводится.

(PS) И нормально ли вообще работает оператор i++; в этом фрагменте кода:

```
  if (str[i + 1] == ' ')
  {
      i++;
      continue;
  }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка?

Comment: Прошлись бы с помощью отладчика и посмотрели бы, что, где и как выполняется. Наверняка бы и ошибку без проблем нашли бы

Comment: Если честно не знал о его предназначении и никогда не пользовался им, щас постараюсь разобратся

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Последний символ теряется из-за условия цикла `i < len - 1`, поскольку он не доходит до конца из-за одновременного знака меньше и вычитания единицы.

В случае, когда перед последним символом стоит пробел, последний символ будет сохранен за счет внутренней ветки `else`:

```
...
else
{
    temp[j] = str[++i];
    j++;
}
...
```

Честно говоря, не очень понятно, зачем нужны все эти внутренние проверки наличия двойных пробелов, но обычную функцию по удалению пробелов я бы написал как-то так:

```
void delSpace(char * str)
{
    int i, j;
    int len = strlen(str);

    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < len; i++)
        if (str[i] != ' ')
            str[j++] = str[i];
    str[j] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Я бы: 1) не позволял модифицировать вход 2) вернул бы указатель на новую строку вместо void :)

Comment: *memchr()* и *memmove()* вылечат этот алгоритм